# Error 45 from web page

Tags: php, mysql

The following query statement does what I want from a MySQL command line but I wish to get the results also on a web page. Here is what I wrote for that, but I just get an error 45.

```
    table colspan="1" align="center" VALIGN="top" border="2" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding     = "5">
<td>
<?php    
$query  = "SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS 'Online Users' FROM opensim.GridUser 
INNER JOIN opensim.UserAccounts ON opensim.UserAccounts.PrincipalID = opensim.GridUser.UserID  WHERE opensim.GridUser.online = 'true';
";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
echo $result ?>
<br><br><br>
When programed this page should show
<br>Grid Users Online Names <br>



 <br><br></td>
 </table>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will not fix your problem if this is a typo, `table colspan="1"` in your code, edit it to `<table colspan="1"` you missed the opening `<`

Comment: Another thing, where are your DB connection infos?

Comment: @Fred-ii- deleted my answer as it was now useless, but wanted to thank you for letting me know the last line containing an echo doesn't need a semi-colon unless a class is used after the fact -- I did not know that! Learn something new every day...

Comment: @Jim My pleasure. I learned that `bit` about using a class a few months ago myself, so I'm "sharing the wealth" as it were ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove single quotes

Try this:

```
$query  = "SELECT concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS Online_Users FROM opensim.GridUser 
INNER JOIN opensim.UserAccounts ON opensim.UserAccounts.PrincipalID = opensim.GridUser.UserID  WHERE opensim.GridUser.online = 'true';
";
```

Comment: TY  I removed the single quotes from above and now get an Resource id #44 error message

Comment: @CloneuInglewood and... did you not see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032503/error-45-from-web-page?noredirect=1#comment28123883_19032503) ? is that your actual code? And where are your DB connections?

Comment: the < was just missing because of a cut and paste but it is there in the code.  the database connection is picked up by the   <?=$this->load->view('header');?><br>  statement that I didnt bother to cut to this

Comment: @CloneuInglewood If and when you do post a future question regarding another possible problem, I suggest you put in as much information as you can and fix typos, that way there will be no confusion and useless questions asked. When something seems evident as in "here's my code" and is right in people's faces, they'll ask questions. *Food for thought* ;-)

Comment: Thanks Fred.. after 2 days of playing with this i found this resource and was "excited" that I might get a fix..  I made changes to the code and now get a new error  
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Online Users

Filename: views/online.php

Line Number: 10
Grrrrrrrrrr

Comment: I just fixed that and it now shows who is online.. THANK YOU so very much everyone for your help with this I greatly appreciate It...John

Comment: @CloneuInglewood You're welcome. Now, you're calling your `FROM opensim.GridUser` and since you probably didn't set up an index for it, may be the problem. I only know "about" this, because to tell you the truth, I only started learning this a few months ago myself, but I don't know what the answer is in regards to it. Try calling your `FROM` using the table's name directly; i.e. `FROM opensim` assuming `opensim` is your table's name, see if that will work, then use `JimiDini's` updated answer about `echo $row['Online_Users']."<br>";` see if that will spark it up.

Comment: @CloneuInglewood ah, problem solved. Great, glad to hear it! Consider accepting the answer by clicking the white checkmark till it turns green, in case you need to know. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Should be like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Online_Users']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: TY for your reply am now getting the error
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Online Users

Filename: views/online.php

Line Number: 10

Comment: @CloneuInglewood ok. I guess you tweaked the query according to the other answer, so it should be `Online_Users`. I fixed my answer